# Android button on top of bitmap background doesnt show up

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-view

I have fooled with this for days but cannot get it to work, although it compiles without error and the apk gets installed in the emulator.  The emulator shows the bitmap (res/drawable/scr0.png) ok but no button shows up nor responds when clicked on.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

//public class PageOne extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
public class PageOne extends Activity  {

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_one);
    setContentView(new myView(this));
    //addListenerOnButton();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page_one, menu);
    return true;
}

private class myView extends View {

    public myView (Context context) {
        super (context);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_one);

        addListenerOnButton();
        //button.bringToFront();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {

        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scr0);
        button.bringToFront();

    }

}// myView

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    button.bringToFront();
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageTwo.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });

}// addListenerOnButton()


}// PageOne


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PageOne" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:text="bubkiss" />

</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yetanotherpageturner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.yetanotherpageturner.PageOne"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.yetanotherpageturner.PageTwo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `button.setOnClickListener(new View().OnClickListener());`
And please vote if it helps.